# How can I get multiEditor rather than IEditor?

Tags: eclipse, editor, eclipse-plugin

Is there a way to get multiEditor rather than just getting IEditor?

```
IEditorPart editor= getSite().getPage().getActiveEditor()
```

to

```
MultiPageEditorPart editor=??
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if the type of the IEditorPart is what you wanted, then cast it to MultiPageEditorPart.

For example:

```
IEditorPart editor= getSite().getPage().getActiveEditor();

if (editor.getClass().isAssignableFrom(MultiPageEditorPart.class)) {
    MultiPageEditorPart  multiPageEditor = (MultiPageEditorPart) editor;

    ...
}
```